# How to add a google map to an existing android studio project

Tags: android, dictionary

I am create an android app where am using android studio as my programming platform. My question is that whether it is possible to create a google map in an EXISTING android studio project. I have seen many places of how to create to a google map in and independent project. But none have shown me how to proceed to creating a google map in an existing one. Help me please!

Comment: whats the difference?

Comment: Um, create an activity, add a `MapFragment` or `SupportMapFragment` to it, etc.

Comment: @CommonsWare: is it possible to do this in an existing one? i mean in my ongoing built android app because i have many places. All are created in an independent app.Can i get the link of how to proceed with it or maybe some useful sample codes?

Comment: @Boss: i dont know how to proceed with creating a map in existing project,hovewer i know how to create it in an independent one. Any help?

Comment: "is it possible to do this in an existing one?" -- an existing one of *what*? If you mean an existing app, then yes: create an activity, add a `MapFragment` or `SupportMapFragment`, etc. This is not significantly different than either creating a new project using Maps V2 or adding any other sort of activity to an existing project. "Can i get the link" -- asking for off-site resources is considered off-topic in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 16):

this answer is so simple and easy.

Simply go to File --> New --> Google -- > Google Map Activity

Answer (score 8):

Old question but for anyone else out there who DOES NOT want to create a new google maps activity just to get the required code you will need to do the following.

In your app `build.gradle`file add the following import:

`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'`

Under `res/values` folder create a new file called `google_maps_api.xml` and enter the following:

```
<resources>
    <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">YOUR_KEY_HERE</string>
</resources>
```

Make sure to replace `YOUR_KEY_HERE` with your google API key.

Next add the following to your `AndroidManifest.xml` within the `application` tag:

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

You can now add the google maps fragment with the following code:

```
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have "Google Play Services" as part of your project.
You can do this by importing "Google Play Services" from your android sdk extras directory.

Then depending upon which Mapping API you are using you may need to obtain a key from the developer console: https://console.developers.google.com/

The key is used in the Manifest to id you to the mapping server.